# Getting records in the last 1 hour using PROC SQL (Teradata)

Tags: sas, teradata, proc-sql

I am using SAS to connect to Teradata. Given the below dataset (it's a transaction table that updates records regularly), I need to be able to select records from the past hour (at least 3). So for example, if I am running the query at 6pm, I should get txn_id 5678, 1985, 2985 (refer to below dataset). Can you please help? This needs to be done in proc sql (connecting to teradata) or even just a SQL query running in Teradata SQL Assistant.

Dataset:

```
TXN_ID Date       Time
1234   20200608   4:00 PM
5678   20200608   5:00 PM
1985   20200608   5:30 PM
2985   20200608   5:45 PM
2365   20200608   2:30 PM
```

Expected Output:

```
TXN_ID Date       Time

5678   20200608   5:00 PM
1985   20200608   5:30 PM
2985   20200608   5:45 PM
```

Comment: Is the timestamp split into two columns? What are the datatypes?

Comment: No, it's a single column. The column "Time" contains the relevant data

Comment: If the column is a Timestamp datatype: `where timestampcolumn >= current_timestamp - interval '1' hour'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `outobs` option :

```
proc sql outobs=3;
    select * from sashelp.class order by Age, Name;
quit;
```

This option is used to limit the number of rows in the output.